# How to adapt ios13 statusbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios13

When I run my project on ios13 xcode11 beta.

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height`

the code returns 0.

what should I do to adapt it to ios13 ?

Comment: Why do you need the status bar height? What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: @rmaddy I need that to layout some custom view

Comment: I'm having the same issue and spent days trying to workaround it. Still no luck. I don't understand why someone "-1" this question and voted to close it.   @rmaddy In my particular case, header's (custom) UI depends on this property being correct.

Comment: I would guess that at the time you're trying to read the statusBarFrame, the size is not clear yet. If you look at the UIApplication headers, you'll see that statusBarFrame is deprecated as of iOS 13 - does using that (in iOS 13) help? Otherwise you'll need to provide some more context & code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use UIStatusBarManager to get the statusBar height in iOS13:

```
UIStatusBarManager *manager = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager;

CGFloat height = manager.statusBarFrame.size.height;
```

Comment: This works okay if you just want a temporary solution, but keyWindow is a deprecated property on UIApplication.

To me it seems as though the status bar is currently buggy--my info.plist specifies that the status bar is light content, but when debugging using the comment above, it evaluates as UIStatusBarStyle.darkContent

Answer (score 0):

SceneDelegate.swift file

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    if let statusBarFrame = windowScene.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame {
        print(statusBarFrame)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As *Peter* noted on *Tamarous's* answer, the *keyWindow* property is deprecated, however on the assumption you're using a single window you can alternatively use:

```
CGSize statusBarSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject.windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame.size
```

If you needed to access the *nth* window, you could do so in a similar manner:

```
NSInteger i = 0;
CGSize statusBarSize = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[i].windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame.size;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
lazy var statusBarHeight = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

Explanation :

You can't use `window` in a `let` because it doesn't exist when that property is created because it belongs to self. So at `init`, `self` isn't complete yet. But if you use a `lazy var`, then `self` and its property `window` will be ready by the time you need it.

Or another solution use `singleton`:

```
struct AppConstants {
    static let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
    static let statusBarHeight = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
}
```